# storing a game score

Tags: c++11, game-center

I have this code in my playGame() which I call from `main`. The code below increments when either player, X / O, either wins or ties, but when I play my full game a second time, I loose my previous score.

Can someone suggest a more efficient way to store the scores?

Desired result: when game is played again, previous score should be kept and incremented if same player with a previous score wins or both ties.

retain previous score, increment if req, ---

```
    //score start at zero.
   int Xwins = 0;
   int Owins = 0;
   int tie = 0;

   if(wins == 'X')
   {
      Xwins++;  //increments Xwins if player X wins
   }
   else if(wins == 'O')
   {
      Owins++;  //increments Owins if player O wins
   }
   else if(NOWIN)
   {
      tie++;   //increments tie if no player wins
   }
```

result when Xwins

### X | O | tie

1 | 0 | 0

play again;
result when Xwins again --- should be 2 not 1 ---- my issue

### X | O | tie

1 | 0 | 0

Comment: I resolved it without additional codes.. thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should store the score value to temporary variable. Then after a new score, you should sum it up on the last score on your temporary variable.

Comment: Create a 2 score variables (Temporary and Actual) then after the game closes or finishes, Sum the temporary score to actual.. then the next open of your application. The last score will be stored on your temporary score. Get it by using a button or a command. Make sure to have two textboxes.

Comment: Set a `tempvariable = 0` and `actualvariable = 0` then create 2 textboxes, 1 for tempvariable and actualvariable each. Create a button or modify an event in which the record on the actualvariable will be stored on the tempvariable. Do not clear the tempvariable to 0 when a form opens in order to create a running total.

Comment: I am lost on "creating two boxes".

Comment: If you are using textboxes for displaying scores. You should create 2 of them. The temporary score would be hidden and the actual score textbox will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

### 1. If you need the score while you are playing (not closing the game and start again)

After a game finishes, You can store the data to a local variable e.g. `temp_score` and then when the new game begins, just sum the `current_score` with `temp_score`

### 2. If you need score even after starting the game

Save the `temp_score` to a file(e.g. score.txt) and when the game starts again, just read the previous score from the file and add up to the current score. after you finish the game again, update new `temp_score` in the file

Comment: i need the score if the player decides to play again... so after each game i want the score stored except game ends

Comment: pls can you write a sample code.. i understand your point to certain extent and i envisage that it would work but i am missing the concept.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Use static variables:**

If `X` and `O` are only two players for whom this function is called, then define `XWins`, `OWins` and `tie` as `static`, so that the value is retained between repeated calls to the same function.

```
  static int Xwins = 0;
  static int Owins = 0;
  static int tie = 0;
```

Comment: this gives ; X | O | tie
------------ 
1570221422 | -2141442022 | 8388447

Comment: I guess you crossed INTMAX. Use long long instead.

Comment: 72198329990600357 | 0 | 0

Comment: X | O | tie
------------ 
1 | 0 | 0       but its not going to save my output-- score. which is my question